# API client for android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am in the process of writing an API client for Android. (I'm not sure if that's the correct term - but what I men is some kind of class that is used to communicate with the API on a web server). The app is targeting Android versions 4.0.3 +. That means that I should use `HTTPURLConnection`.

I have a hard time putting all the documentation together, but my question is basically if this is the best way to do it:

If we imagine that the website api have the following structure:

`http://www.example.com/api/resource/resource1.json`

`http://www.example.com/api/resource/resource2.json`

`http://www.example.com/api/somethingelse/random1.json`

Would I then create an `AsyncTask` for each of the resources I would like to fetch? Say that I have a view that wants to display data from all of the three resources (resource1, resource2 and random1). And then close the connection and the `AsyncTask`. The whole example is of course pretty silly, but is that what you would do?

The thing I'm concerned about is that AsyncTasks introduces a multi-threaded environment and `HTTPURLConnection` doesn't support it. Also I want the code to be as easy and effective as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding easy and effective is a good plan. Thus, you should use one of the existing libraries for this task and not invent everything from scratch. I did this my self for some time, but when you have used e.g. loopj's [Android Async Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) you will never do that again.

It's a few lines of code, implementing a callback for handling the results and you're done.

Just [have a look who is using it](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/details/loopj_asynchttpclient/android-asynchronous-http-client) (e.g. Spotify, Instagram, Pinterest ...) and you'll be sold.

Comment: Yes, better don't write your client with native `HttpURLConnection`. There are more libraries [listed here](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It is one of the good library to consume web APIs.